# Ordering a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv

I have this code

```
archivo=open("archivo.csv","r")
for i in range(10):
    for reg in archivo:
        if archivo[reg] < archivo[reg+1]:
            x = archivo[reg]
            archivo[reg] = archivo[reg+1]
            archivo[reg+1] = x
archivo.close()
archivo = open("archivo.csv","w")
archivo.write(reg)
```

What i want is to order alphabetically the files and to save it ordered, but i have several errors. The main one says that the file has not atribute getitem and in the web i didn't find anything equal. Can someone help me?

Input looks like

```
Matt | 7 | 8 
John | 9 | 6 
Jim | 6 | 7
```

Comment: What does the input look like? Only a few lines would suffice. Also why `for i in range(10):`. There would only be lines to read one time so the other 9 iterations would do nothing. Basically what you need to do is read each line into some sort of form where they can be compared and ordered, at present you are just comparing strings holding the lines themselves. Consider also you have the `csv` module at your disposal, which might simply your task if you are able to use it.

Comment: The for line is because if an item in position 7 that starts with an "a" for example is ordered once, it wouldn't be in the first position. If you have another system of ordering file lines please share it because is not specific.

Comment: And i don't get what input are you talking about

Comment: It's good to see a sample of your input file archivo.csv so we don't need to generate test files of our own. One thing that seems to me to be a problem is that you're using `reg` as if it is an index - it is actually a component of archivo, not an index.

Comment: What do you think `archivo[reg]` is supposed to do? The error is telling you that isn't valid.

Comment: The file looks like this. There are 3 columns: The name that is the criterion of ordering, and 2 marks

Comment: I don't know how to upload the file so i will copy it.    Matt | 7 | 8 (another line) John | 9 | 6 (another one) Jim | 6 | 7 and like this

Comment: And how can i use an index to follow that for line?

Comment: I edited your question with the sample data. If it isn't how it should be you can edit again.

Comment: Oh thank you thats better

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the source CSV file to be comma separated. So `archivo.csv` looks like

```
Matt,7,8
John,9,6
Jim,6,7
```

Now to read this file, python already has standard module called `csv`. Using that we can read and write csv reliably.

```
from  csv import reader, writer
archivo=reader(open("archivo.csv","r"))
a = sorted(archivo)
archivo1 = writer(open("archivo1.csv", "w"))
for row in a:
    archivo1.writerow(row)
```